# How to set up rule based offset points symbology in QGIS

Tags: qgis, rule-based, offset

I use QGIS 3.22.2 and I have points datasets of records from ecology surveys with column of "ID" of individual record and column "Species" with few different values (for example: 'Pip', 'Pop', 'Pep' and 'Pap') and I need to make rule based symbology with different symbols for different "Species", almost all of records from same species will have same offset points (0,0), but to avoid points overlapping I need for some records of same "Species" - for example: "Species"='Pip' - with given particular "ID" - for example "ID"='2' I would like to have offset points set up on (3,4) and for "ID"='5' I would like to have offset points set up on (5,6), etc.

How and where I can set up this kind of Rule-based symbology in QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the data defined override of the symbol offset `x` and `y` with an expression, like so:

[image]

###### Expression

```sql
case 
    when $id = 2 then '3,4'
    when $id = 5 then '5,6'
    --else '7,8' -- you can also use `else` in a `case` statement (delete the leading -- to uncomment)
end
```

If you don't use `else` in the above statement, the `id`s not caught by the expression (everything other than `2` and `5`) will be unaffected (`0,0` offset).

###### Result

[image]

*I use the `Meters at scale` measurement unit for some extra distance in my screenshot*

Comment: Thanks Matt it works now, it was what I needed

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)